# GCP BigQuery - bq tool load pipe-delimited file errors when one of the column has a delimited even though it is in double quotes

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a file with the following three columns. File is pipe-delimited and data is enclosed in double quotes. I am trying to use bq command to load the data from google storage bucket into a bigquery table and encounter the below error

**Sample File**

```
ticket|identification|detail
"X789678"|"New dept|location|name"|"this is a new department quote"
```

**Command used**
`bq load --replace --skip_leading_rows=1 --allow_jagged_rows=true --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter="|" --preserve_ascii_control_characters=true --allow_quoted_newlines=true --quote "" mydataset.ticket_details gs://test_bucket/Tickets*.txt`

**Error**
Error while reading data, error message:

> Too many values in line. Found 5 column(s) when expecting 3.;
> line_number: 2 byte_offset_to_start_of_line:

I tried bq command using various options. Seems like bq does not load data when the delimiter is in the data even though it is enclosed within double quotes

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is that it interpret `|` inside the columns as a delimiter, to fix the issue you have to pass double quote character `"` as the quoting symbol: `--quote '"'`:

```
bq load --replace --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter="|" mydataset.ticket_details gs://test_bucket/Tickets*.txt
```

Alternatively, you can remove `--quote` argument because the default value is double quote.

Comment: Hi, Using the above command with --quote '"' gives me the following error. I am running this directly in Google SDK
Not enough positional args, still looking for destination_table

Comment: @msk The command I provided is not including all the parameters , make sure you are including all the necessary parameters, including `project_id:dataset_id.table_id`

Comment: thank you for the response. Yes, I am passing the complete command as below:
bq load --project_id=my-project-id --replace --skip_leading_rows=1 --allow_jagged_rows=true --source_format=CSV --field_delimiter="|" --preserve_ascii_control_characters=true --allow_quoted_newlines=true --quote '"' mydataset.ticket_details gs://test_bucket/Tickets*.txt

This results in "Not enough positional args, still looking for destination_table" error.

If I use the same command without --quote or with --quote "" the data is parsed but the delimited within the quotes is not considered correctly

Comment: @msk so maybe it has to do with escaping quote or double quote character in bash. Remove `quote` parameter all together, the default value is already `"` character